# XSLT dynamically set count in paged transform?

Tags: xslt, apache-cocoon

Is it possible to dynamically set the value of the "count" param below?

```
<map:transform type="filter" label="paged">
    <map:parameter name="use-request-parameters" value="true" />
    <map:parameter name="element-name" value="course" />
    <map:parameter name="count" value="20" />
    <map:parameter name="blocknr" value="{1}" />
</map:transform>
```

For instance, if I delete the following line from above:

```
<map:parameter name="count" value="20" />
```

and create a hidden field in my form that calls the transform that uses the filter:

```
<input type="hidden" name="count" value="40" />
```

then grab the param when I'm in the transform that uses the filter:

```
<xsl:param name="count" />
```

shouldn't the *xsl:template match="block"* be able to use the *count* param passed in the form?

It's not working for me as outlined above, so I wanted to see if anyone knows if it's even possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `<map:parameter name="count" value="20" />` is a literal result element then you can use `<map:parameter name="count" value="{$count}" />` to make use of the XSLT parameter or variable named `count`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a hidden field named "count" on a search form. When I click Submit, I land on a results page that contains data produced from an XSL filter resource. The count value is used to determine how many results to show on the page. When I hard-code the value in the map:param in the Sitemap, it works. When I use my first method above, as well as having just tried to use {$count} to get the value from the hidden field on the form, it doesn't work. Not sure why as I'm able to get the other form field values.

Comment: It seems you are using some server-side processing related to that `map:transform` stuff you have shown. It seems to me that you should identify that server-side framework and tag your question with it, as the solution might need require knowledge of the interaction of XSLT with that framework. It is not purely an XSLT problem.